# Mismatched Magento version while using composer

Tags: magento2, theme, composer, php-7.2

I currently have Magento running on **Ubuntu Xampp**, and attempted to run composer on a theme file, which prompted me to install a load of PHP extensions. I did this (7.2 for all of them, same as system version) which fixed those errors, but then it suddenly came up with

> magento/framework 100.0.9 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your
>   PHP version (7.2.15) does not satisfy that requirement.

This is in response to `composer install` in the relevant theme folder.

However, the Magento admin panel clearly states that I'm on version 2.3.1 which does support **PHP 7.2.11** (which is earlier than 7.2.15, but surely this shouldn't be a breaking change). I installed Magento through the bitnami addon installer to Xampp, which could be the cause as it somehow installed an older version? (Although again, admin panel states I'm running 2.3.1). **Could this be something to do with the version the theme in specific is looking for?**

Any advice would be very appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **`third party extension`** it could be the reason why you got that error. The solution would be either disable first or uininstall that extension or look for that third party extension's **`composer.json`** file and find **`required PHP version`**, if your current PHP version is not available in the `"require"` then please add it.

Do it like below:

```
"require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|7.2.15"
    },
```